# SciPy Optimization algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, optimization, scipy

I need to solve an optimization task with Python.
The task is following:

> Fabric produces  desks, chairs, bureau and cupboards. For producing this stuff two types of boards could be used. Fabric has 1500m. of first type and 1000m. of second. Fabric has 800 Employees. What should produce fabric and how much to receive a maximum profit?

The input values are following:

```
|              |           Products               |
|              | Desk | Chair | Bureau | Cupboard |
|--------------|------|-------|--------|----------|
| Board 1 type | 5    | 1     | 9      | 12       |
| Board 2 type | 2    | 3     | 4      | 1        |
| Employees    | 3    | 2     | 5      | 10       |
| Profit       | 12   | 5     | 15     | 10       |
```

Unfortunately I don't have an experience in solving optimization tasks so I don't even know where to start. What I did:

1. I found sciPy optimization package which suppose to solve such type of problems.
2. I have some vision about input and output for my function. The input should amount of each type of product and the output supposed to be the profit. But the choice of resources(boards, employees) might also be different. And this affects algorithm implementation.

Could you please give me at least any direction where to go? Thank you!

EDIT:
Basically @Balzola is right. It's a simplex algorithm. The task might be solved by using [SciPy.optimize.linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) solution which uses simplex under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm

Looks like scipy can do it:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#nelder-mead-simplex-algorithm-method-nelder-mead

Comment: ```Simplex-algorithm != Nelder-mead```. scipy.optimize.linprog is the correct candidate, but it's quite bad.

Comment: @sascha What would you recommend?

Comment: Open-source & free: Cbc, GLPK, lpsolve (in this order). Open-source, but non-free: SCIP. Commercial: Gurobi, Cplex Mosek and co. I recommend cvxpy (which may need some work at install-time to make CBC/GLPK ready; the default-solver ECOS can solve LPs too and is also much better than linprog). Or use pulp, which is easier to install and brings cbc out of the box, even on windows (i don't like the design of this lib in regards to erroneous constraints but i will work if the user is careful).

Comment: There exist two unrelated Simplex methods: the Simplex Method for linear programming and a simplicial algorithm for nonlinear optimization (aka Nelder-Mead).